# Find nearest Vector2(x,y) in collection

Tags: c#, search, nearest-neighbor

I have a `bool[,]`, and given an input `Vector2(x,y)`, I want to find the indices of the nearest `true`. I can naively loop through the 2d array and check the distances to the input, but that'll give me a runtime of O(LxW). I'm wondering if there's any faster way of finding the nearest than O(LxW). I'm open to adding all the true coordinates in a `Hashset<Vector2>` or a sorted `List<Vector2>` or any other type of collection, if it'll net a quicker lookup.

Performance is more critical than code readability here.

Example:

```
T, T, F
T, F, T
T, T, T

GetNearestTrue(new Vector2(2, 3)) // returns (1, 2)
GetNearestTrue(new Vector2(1, 1)) // returns (0, 1) or (1, 0) or (1, 2) or (2, 1), since they're equidistant it doesn't matter
```

Comment: If you have the `true`'s in a lookup, you could just subtract the `true`'s from the origin and see which one is closest.

Comment: @Stefan I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Let's say you have a 100 by 100 grid and 3 `true`'s. Since they are in a lookup table you get 3 sets of `x,y`'s, lets call them T1, T2, T3. Then the smallest `|Tx - PointOfInterest|` is your nearest point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there's any faster way of finding the nearest than O(LxW)?

If the L and W are length and width for the 2d array respectively then the answer is no.

Simple proof:
Imagine you have to prove that there is no nearest true in the grid. I.E. the grid consists only false. You can never say there is none until you have visited every single cell of the grid. Which means the run time will always be at least O(LxW).

In order to prove the node (x, y) is the nearest to (a, b) you must prove that there consists only false in the circle around (a,b) with radius `|Max(x-a, y-b)|`  And in the worst case the radius will be the `Max(L, W)` which makes the worst case run time O(LxW)

Though you could do some optimization by doing a BFS from the center, this will reduce the runtime by some factors but the worse case stays the same.

Comment: I should mention that the grid data won't change often, so putting all trues in a `List<Vector2>` will result in a max O(N) rather than O(LxW). With that specification, is there a way to sort the list to achieve O(LogN)? Maybe 2 lists, one sorted by `x` first, the other sorted by `y` first, then compare the output of both lists to see which is closer?

Comment: @Tim depending on how much pre calculation you want to do. if that grid doesn't change often and you need lots of lookup then you can just pre compute the result for every combination of x and y. Then when you actually want to find the result it will take O(1)

Comment: I can't precompute every combo, that'd take up ~4 billion x 4 billion Vector2s. No computer has that much memory.

Comment: @Tim your HashSet for all true will take up the same amount of ram as the true false grid which takes equal amount of ram for the precompute grid.

Comment: I suppose I could precompute for each cell in the grid, then anything outside the grid just recalculates to be the nearest edge cell and  looks up that way. Yeah, I think that could work. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim unless I misunderstood something, all combinations of x, y is just the whole grid. x = W, y = L.

Comment: Except that input can be outside of the grid bounds, which is easy to project to the nearest edge cell of the grid.

Comment: There is a faster way, even for your worst case. The trick is to store only the 'true' values, then you can get below O(L*W), see my own answer.

Comment: @TilmannZ if you have a way to find all the `true` values without going thru the whole grid then you will be the next billionaire. If you ignore the precompute time complexity then I have already provided a O(1) algorithm

Comment: From the comments I assumed that finding all the 'true' values in the matrix has to be done only once, but the search will be repeated on a true/value set that "does not change often". I also assumed that we get notified when the values change, so we don't have to check the whole matrix before each search. If these assumptions are wrong, then you are right, it is O(L\*W) per search. But if they are right, then we may need O(L\*W) only rarely (or even only once, if we get notified _which_ values change). After that we can perform each search with O(log n). Did I overlook something?

Comment: @TilmannZ If we are allowed to do pre compute then O(1) algorithm exists. Check my earlier comment

Comment: @Steve Sorry, my fault, you are correct. But I think it depends on the circumstances. Full pre-compute is useful if there are lots of 'true' and (as you wrote) if the values rarely change; it also has O(L\*W) space complexity. My own proposal would make sense if there are few 'true' values (space complexity O(nTrue) ) or if values change more frequently, but only few values change in each step (this would make an incremental update cheaper than a full scan to recompute the precomputed result (a partial recomputation would require an multi-dim index to be efficient)).

Answer (score 2):

If you you have a significant number of 'false', then there is a faster way. You can optimize from O(L*W)=O(nFalse + nTrue) to *about* O(log nTrue).

You can use a multidim-index (quadtree, kd-tree, R-Plus-Tree, PH-Tree) and insert for every 'true' at (x,y) a point into the multi-dim index with coordinates (x,y).
Now, to find the nearest 'true' for a point 'p', you just do a nearest-neighbor search in the index for point 'p'. For example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) says that there is an algorithm "that claims guaranteed O(log n) complexity."

While kd-tree is possibly the simplest (see [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes) for Java implementation for many indexes), the PH-Tree may make sense because it can work directly with integers as coordinate, rather than floating point values. However, I'm not aware of a C# version of the PH-Tree.